# What are the default button mappings for the Thrustmaster Ferrari GT Experience?

Tags: ps3

The title says it all, really. [This](http://www.thrustmaster.com/product.aspx?ProductID=84&PlatformID=12) steering wheel was bought for me as a Christmas present, and I'd like to map some of its buttons to different functions. How do they map to a standard PS3 controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can [download the user manual](http://ts.thrustmaster.com/eng/index.php?pg=view_files&gid=3&fid=15&pid=246&cid=6) from the *Updates and Downloads* section of Thrustmaster's support site.  (Here's a [direct link](http://ts.thrustmaster.com/faqs/eng/thr_eng_00107.pdf) to the PDF.)

It contains a picture of how the buttons map to the PS3 controller on page 1.  Pages 5 and 6 explain how to program the buttons.